# String Functions for Nested Schema in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am learning Spark in Scala programming language.

Input file ->
"Personal":{"ID":3424,"Name":["abcs","dakjdb"]}}

Schema ->

```
root
  |-- Personal: struct (nullable = true)
  |    |-- ID: integer (nullable = true)
  |    |-- Name: array (nullable = true)
  |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

Operation for output ->
I want to concat the Strings of "Name" element
Eg - abcs|dakjdb

I am reading the file using dataframe API. 
Please help me from this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be pretty straightforward if you are working with Spark >= 1.6.0 you can use `get_json_object` and `concat_ws`:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{get_json_object, concat_ws}

val df = Seq(
  ("""{"Personal":{"ID":3424,"Name":["abcs","dakjdb"]}}"""),
  ("""{"Personal":{"ID":3425,"Name":["cfg","woooww"]}}""")
)
.toDF("data")

df.select(
  concat_ws(
    "-", 
    get_json_object($"data", "$.Personal.Name[0]"), 
    get_json_object($"data", "$.Personal.Name[1]")
  ).as("FullName")
).show(false)

// +-----------+
// |FullName   |
// +-----------+
// |abcs-dakjdb|
// |cfg-woooww |
// +-----------+
```

With `get_json_object` we go through the json data an extract the two elements of the `Name` array which we concatenate later on.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But when i gave schema as StructType(List(StructField("Personal", StructType(List(
            StructField("ID",IntegerType,true),
            StructField("Name",ArrayType(StringType,true)))))
        )) It is getting failed.

Comment: get_json_object doesn't get any schema, it will parse the json and extract the desired data based on the specified selector i.e: "$.Personal.Name[0]".

Comment: If you need to be able to validate your schema though you must use from_json. This will store the json as a struct. Finally you can use Spark selectors to extract your data

Answer (score 0):

There is an inbuilt function [concat_ws](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#concat_ws(java.lang.String,%20scala.collection.Seq)) which should be useful here.

Comment: can you please give me idea through some sample code.

Comment: I have tried below code but getting ExpressionEncoder error \n val value = readFile.select("Personal").map(r => {
      val array = r.isInstanceOf[mutable.WrappedArrayBuilder]
      array.toString.concat("|")
    })(RowEncoder(schema1))

Answer (score 0):

to extend @Alexandros Biratsis answer. you can first convert Name into array[String] type before concatenating to avoid writing every name position. Querying by position would also fail when the value is null or when only one value exist instead of two.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{get_json_object, concat_ws, from_json}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{ArrayType, StringType}

val arraySchema = ArrayType(StringType)

val df = Seq(
  ("""{"Personal":{"ID":3424,"Name":["abcs","dakjdb"]}}"""),
  ("""{"Personal":{"ID":3425,"Name":["cfg","woooww"]}}""")
)
.toDF("data")
.select(get_json_object($"data", "$.Personal.Name") as "name")
.select(from_json($"name", arraySchema) as "name")
.select(concat_ws("|", $"name"))
.show(false)
```